Intermittent GET Request Timeouts with Basic Auth on VMWare NSX V 6.4 API
I am working with the VMWare NSX V 6.4 API and encountering an issue with intermittent timeouts when making GET requests to https://{NSX-MANAGER-HOST}/api/4.0/edges/edge-10/ipsec/statistics using Basic Authentication. The timeouts occur randomly and do not correlate with specific times or load conditions.
Here's a brief overview of the situation:

Method: GET requests
URL: https://{NSX-MANAGER-HOST}/api/4.0/edges/edge-10/ipsec/statistics
Auth: Basic Authentication
Issue: Random timeouts

I've confirmed that the issue is not related to network instability or server overload at the times when timeouts occur. I have tried making these requests from different hosts within our infrastructure, confirming that the issue is not host-specific. I'm looking for guidance on where to find relevant logs or diagnostics that could help pinpoint the cause of these timeouts, or any configuration settings in NSX that might influence this behavior.
Has anyone experienced similar issues or does anyone have suggestions on how to troubleshoot or resolve this problem?
